# Strict-Transport-Security Header only have max-age

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, hsts

I have developed a web application using dotnet 6 and deployed on Azure App Service.

I found out that a Strict-Transport-Security only have value **max-age=31536000** instead of **max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains;preload**

[image]

I have a try a few methods, but it's not working.

Method 1 : Rewrite rules

```
<rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="(.*)" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
                <outboundRules>
                    <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
                        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security" pattern=".*" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains;preload" />
                    </rule>
                </outboundRules>
            </rewrite>
```

Method 2 : Add Custom Header

```
<add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" />
```

Method 3 : program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddHsts(options =>
{
    options.Preload = true;
    options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
    options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
});

app.UseHsts();
```

Comment: Check whether you have enabled HSTS in the environment you are checking.

Comment: Could you please share your Program.cs file.

Comment: Iam able to see the options which I have set.Will post an answer in detail.

Answer (score 0):

As per this MSDoc [Enforce HTTPS in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Clinux-ubuntu#http-strict-transport-security-protocol-hsts)

> `UseHsts` isn't recommended in development

I have set the `UseHsts` as below and able to see all settings in the deployed WebApp.

`app.UseHsts()`  has to be for the other Environments other than Development.

***My `Program.cs` file:***

```cs
using System.Net;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddHsts(options =>
{
    options.Preload = true;
    options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
    options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);   
});
//builder.Services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
//{
//    options.RedirectStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect;
//    options.HttpsPort = 5001;
//});
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error"); 
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

Re-deploy the Application.Run the URL.

***Output:***

[image]